# The terminal process command '/usr/bin/bash' failed to launch (exit code: 1)

Tags: vscode-debugger

error when i open the terminal, the error info is "The terminal process command '/usr/bin/bash' failed to launch (exit code: 1)"

Comment: now you could theoretically add a few code examples like the command you are entering or the circumstances

Comment: or if you tried that on a windows os

Answer (score 1):

It long looks like your terminal program has been configured to run /usr/bin/bash when it starts; that's not where bash is normally installed. Dig through its menus to find something like "initial command" and correct that to /bin/bash, or whatever shell you want that's installed on the system.

Answer (score 1):

delete $HOME/.config/Code and $HOME/.vscode will solve this

Comment: Not solved, i don't have Code folder and .vscode folder too.